# Blender cycles motion blur and particles from particle instance

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles, baking, instances, motion-blur

I have:
 - one particle system which act in some way
 - i have an object ( sphere ) which has particle instance on it. So it behaves like the particle instance. On that object i added second particle system. Now every sphere is generating small objects from it.

the problem is with motion blur on those small objects generated from many spheres. Where i do not bake second particle system, the motion blur on those works fine. When i do bake on them i seems not to work.
image shows bake done and not done [image]

I have no idea why baking removes motion blur effect from it. I can provide file but the problem is explained above.
Thanks for any help... so important for me.